(All) (the) fermented garlic cloves sold in Japan taste fairly sweet
(1) Fermented garlic cloves sold in Japan taste fairly sweet.
(2) Almost all fermented garlic cloves sold in Japan taste fairly sweet.
(3) The fermented garlic cloves sold in Japan taste fairly sweet.
(4) All the fermented garlic cloves sold in Japan taste fairly sweet.
Are all these sentences possible?
I assume:
(1) and (2) are identical in meaning.
and
(3) and (4) are identical in meaning.

I think your distinction between #1 and #3 is largely / completely spurious. Certainly no UK court would ever accept any such distinction as being legally credible, and I suggest few if any native Anglophones would consciously recognize it as credible and / or useful. All you've got here is that all is emphatic / literal, and almost explicitly denies !00%

You are looking at minor nuance, and should remember the headline:  Context matters more than grammar.
For 1, 3, and 4, I'd mostly understand that there is a product "Fermented garlic", and the Japanese variety of this product is sweet.
Now all three have a restrictive participle phrase "sold in Japan".  Which (if I ignore context) suggests that you are contrasting the Japanese product with the "fermented garlic not sold in Japan" (which by contrast does not taste sweet).  If I'm being mindlessly literal, I could even take (1) to mean that it is sweet as a result of being sold in Japan (if it was sold elsewhere, or given away it would be bitter). That contradicts my general knowledge of how "selling" affects flavour.  It doesn't fit the context, so I understand 1, 3 and 4 to have the same general meaning.
The second has a different meaning, as it says that some don't taste sweet.
Using "The" shows you are speaking specifically about the Japanese product, and would be likely if in the paragraph you were comparing fermented garlic from different countries.
Using "All" is emphatic, it would contrast with "some". The context in which you are using the sentence might justify highlighting this contrast (all of it is sweet, but some of it is sticky)

Thank you very much, JamesK. I am a physically handicapped self-learner of English and have never been to a foreign country, so I don't even know whether fermented garlic cloves are known to most people in the UK/US, so I think it might be dangerous to say "Fermented garlic taste fairly sweet". For what it's worth, it is extremely difficult for Japanese learners of English to understand English articles. In fact, some Japanese teachers who teach English at universities occasionally make mistakes with English articles.

Femented garlic isn't common. I suppose the "Japanese" type is the misozuke.  I don't think it's dangerous.  But articles are very difficult.  But fear not.  if you are confident, people won't notice mistakes.  It is only when you hesitate that you don't sound natural.

I'm a bit surprised that you know the word "misozuke". I should have stated that I was talking about fermented garlic cloves that look black when peeled.

I lived in Japan for 8 years

I'd call the black ones "Black garlic".  I didn't know it was "fermented", I thought it was very slowly baked, at ultra low temperature.
